# How to Get and Validate a Value From Form 2 to Form 1 Using Vb.net

Tags: forms

I have one Button and Textbox in Form 1 and in Form 2 I have one textbox. When i click the Button on Form 1, it should get the value from Textbox of Form 2 and It should also validate the Value is numeric or text.

Please Help Me...

Answer (score 0):

Instanciate Form2 and assign it to a variable and change the modifier of your textBox in Form2 to public in the Designer-file.
Then you can simply access the value of Form2 in Form1.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple way

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```